# Invocar y devolver valor de funciones en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

En el sucesivo código obtengo dos párrafos con valor **67** e **Ivan**, respectivamente, que provienen ambos del valor de la variable **x**.

Mi duda es por qué en el segundo párrafo **x** toma el valor de **x** cuando esta se inicializó y no el valor de `myFunction`.

`var a`, `let b`, el segundo `return` después del primero dentro de la función, son tan solo pruebas.

```js
var a;
let b;
a = 33;
b = 34;
var x = "Ivan";

var x = myFunction(a, b);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

function myFunction(a, b) {
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x;
  return a + b;
    return a * b;

}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El segundo párrafo (*demo2*) devuelve x porque al entrar a la función **myFunction**, el valor de x es "Iván"
Al terminar la función el valor de **x** es **67**, y así lo mostrará el primer párrafo (*demo*)

```js
    var a;
    let b;
    a = 33;
    b = 34;
    var x = "Ivan";

    var x = myFunction(a, b); // 1er paso: se entra a la función
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x; //3er paso: Una vez terminada la función, 
//x valdrá 67, por lo que eso mostrará el p de id="demo"

    function myFunction(a, b) {
      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x; //2do paso: acá x sigue valiendo "Iván", 
//por lo que el p con id="demo2" va a contener el valor "Iván"
      return a + b;
        return a * b;

    }
```

```html
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación Andrés! Me queda solo una duda. 
Entiendo que al entrar en `function myFunction` **x** aun no ha recibido el `return`, luego `var x = 'Ivan`.
Pero, ¿por qué lo que comentas como 3er paso no se ejecuta por orden, después del 1er paso?

Comment: En realidad las instrucciones sí se están ejecutando en orden. Al llamar a una función, el flujo de ejecución del programa principal se detiene justo en la línea donde lo llamamos (en tu caso se **invoca** a **myFunction** en la línea 7 del programa principal) y el control del flujo de ejecución pasa a la función (se empiezan a ejecutar las instrucciones dentro de **myFunction**)

Comment: En este caso, el flujo se puede representar así: (ln = línea) ln 5: var x="Iván"| ln 7: x= **myFunction** (se invoca a la función, x sigue valiendo "Iván")| ln 7 ln1: demo2 imprime x("Iván")| ln 7 ln 2: **myFunction** retorna 67(pasamos al programa principal)| ln 7: x=67| ln 8: demo imprime x(67)|fin del programa.

Answer (score 0):

Te copio el código a lo que entiendo a tu pregunta. Lo que pones entre parentesis en tu función no son los valores que declaras anteriormente, si no, son variable que deberás iniciar cuando ejecutes esa función.

> Por ejemplo he declarado tu variables como x, y, nombre. Estas serán la variables que le pasaré posteriormente a mi función. Pero como puedes ver la función.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>

//Variable
const x = 33;
const y = 34;
const nombre = "Ivan"

//Función con tres parámetros
function myFunction(a, b, name) {
  const suma = a+b;
  const mult = a*b;
   return name + " " + suma + " " + mult;
}

//Le paso a la función los parámetros implícitos escribiéndolos.
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = myFunction(35,20,'Pablo')

//Le paso las variables anteriormente establecidas.
document.getElementById('demo2').innerHTML = myFunction(x,y,nombre)
</script>
```

Espero que te haya ayudado

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]. El OP (autor de la pregunta) sabe cuál es el problema (de hecho lo menciona en la pregunta), lo que no sabe es _por qué_ se da ese comportamiento.

Comment: Gracias Pablo Martinez. Pero como indica @padaleiana, mi pregunta es el porqué de ese comportamiento.
Más específicamente, no entiendo porqué para **demo2** toma el valor inicializado antes de la función y no el mismo que para **demo** .
Alguna idea?

Comment: Voy a agregar otra respuesta para contestarte. @IvanSanczewski

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por la dedicación Pablo. Sin embargo, tu solución, pese a arreglar mi código, sigue sin responder a la pregunta… Voy a releer la respuesta con más aceptación, porque me parece que van por ahí los tiros, hehe ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Si te das cuenta estas realizando dos return cosa que no se puede, por lo tanto cuando llamas a esta función al principio solo te genera la suma ya que pasas como valores el 33 y 34.
>
> Sin embargo en la creación de la función, como aun no estas añadiendo valores ya que a y b son parámetros que utiliza esa función, directamente te devuelve el valor X que has establecido anteriormente en "Ivan" por que no sabe que return devolverte.

```
var a;
let b;
a = 33;
b = 34;
var x = "Ivan";

var x = myFunction(a, b);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

function myFunction(a, b) {
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x;
  return a + b;
    return a * b;

}


P
```

Comment: Haciendo una prueba rápida (léase: eliminando el `return` extra), sigue devolviendo lo mismo.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo! El segundo `return` era el original, inserté el primero para comprobar yo mismo que la función se detiene justo ahí.